# Entity Framework Code First Existing Database set EntityState.Unchanged on Many-to-Many

Tags: c#, entity-framework, entity-framework-6

I have an existing database I'm coding against with Entity Framework 6 Code First. I have a many-to-many relationship that is working for Selects, Inserts and Deletes. I'm having an issue with EF adding an extra insert to the many-to-many table for an existing relationship.

Schema: 
[image]

DbContext:

```
    protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
       Database.SetInitializer<MainContext>(null);

       modelBuilder.Entity<DocumentType>()
                .HasMany(u => u.DocumentStatuses)
                .WithMany()
                .Map(m =>
                {
                    m.MapLeftKey("DOCUMENT_TYPE_ID");
                    m.MapRightKey("DOCUMENT_STATUS_ID");
                    m.ToTable("DOCUMENT_TYPES_DOCUMENT_STATUSES");
                });

       base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);
    }
```

DTOs:

```
    [Table("DOCUMENT_TYPES")]
    public class DocumentType
    {
        [Key]
        [Column("DOCUMENT_TYPE_ID")]
        public int? Id { get; set; }

        [Required]
        [Column("TYPE_NAME")]
        public string TypeName { get; set; }

        [Required]
        [Column("IS_ACTIVE")]
        public bool IsActive { get; set; }

        [Display(Name = "Updated By")]
        [Column("LAST_UPDATED_BY")]
        public string LastUpdatedBy { get; set; }

        [Display(Name = "Updated Date")]
        [Column("LAST_UPDATED_DATE")]
        public DateTimeOffset? LastUpdatedDate { get; set; }

        public virtual List<DocumentStatus> DocumentStatuses { get; set; } 

        public DocumentType()
        {
            DocumentStatuses = new List<DocumentStatus>();
        }
    }

[Table("DOCUMENT_STATUSES")]
public class DocumentStatus
{
    [Key]
    [Column("DOCUMENT_STATUS_ID")]
    public int? Id { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [Column("STATUS_NAME")]
    public string StatusName { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [Column("IS_COMPLETE")]
    public bool IsComplete { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [Column("IS_ACTIVE")]
    public bool IsActive { get; set; }

    [Display(Name = "Updated By")]
    [Column("LAST_UPDATED_BY")]
    public string LastUpdatedBy { get; set; }

    [Display(Name = "Updated Date")]
    [Column("LAST_UPDATED_DATE")]
    public DateTimeOffset? LastUpdatedDate { get; set; }
}
```

Repository Update:

```
    public bool Update(DocumentType entity, string updatedBy)
            {
                DateTimeOffset updatedDateTime = DateTimeOffset.Now;

                entity.LastUpdatedBy = updatedBy;
                entity.LastUpdatedDate = updatedDateTime;

                using (var db = new MainContext())
                {
                    db.DocumentTypes.Add((DocumentType)entity);
                    db.Entry(entity).State = EntityState.Modified;

                    foreach (var item in entity.DocumentStatuses)
                    {
                        if (item.Id != null)
                            db.Entry(item).State = EntityState.Unchanged;
                    }

                    db.SaveChanges();
                }

                return true;
            }
```

The loop that contains:

```
    if (item.Id != null)
     db.Entry(item).State = EntityState.Unchanged;
```

Prevents new records from being added, but EF still tries to insert into DOCUMENT_TYPES_DOCUMENT_STATUSES a duplicate of the existing many-to-many records.

Unit Test:

```
        [TestMethod()]
        public void UpdateTest()
        {
            DocumentTypeRepository documentTypeRepository = new DocumentTypeRepository();
            DocumentType type = NewDocumentType(true);
            DocumentType typefromDb;
            string updatedBy = "DocumentTypeRepositoryTests.UpdateTest";
            bool actual;

            type.IsActive = true;
            type.TypeName = RandomValues.RandomString(18);
            type.DocumentStatuses.Add(DocumentStatusRepositoryTests.NewDocumentStatus(true));

            actual = documentTypeRepository.Update(type, updatedBy);
            Assert.AreEqual(true, actual);

            typefromDb = documentTypeRepository.GetById((int)type.Id);
            Assert.AreEqual(type.DocumentStatuses.Count, typefromDb.DocumentStatuses.Count);
        }
```

How can I set the many-to-many table to EntityState.Unchanged when it already exists?

Answer (score 1):

Try replacing

```
db.DocumentTypes.Add((DocumentType)entity);
db.Entry(entity).State = EntityState.Modified;
```

with

```
db.Entry(entity).State = entity.Id == null 
    ? EntityState.Added
    : EntityState.Modified;
```

When doing CRUD operations with detached entities, it's easier not to use the DbSet operations and only manipulate entity state entries. At least, it leads to less errors.

Comment: I did have a line above the using that checked for id:
if (entity.Id == null)
                throw new InvalidOperationException("DocumentTypeId cannot be null on updates.");

I removed it to keep the example cleaner. The interesting thing is that I by pass the error with your example, but it doesn't save any new Statuses added to the list, just retains the old one.

Comment: The critical part is removing the .Add

Comment: I've added my Unit Test above, when I add a new Status item to the list and Update (with the new code), it doesn't add the new item to the many-to-many table. So the last assert fails because it only has the first Status instead of two.

Comment: @Josh Frank is right, but there's more involved than meets the eye. I explained it in an answer. A comment didn't do.

Answer (score 1):

Two things are important to note here:

1. When you `Add` an entity to a context, the whole object graph owned by the entity is marked as `Added`.
2. In any association this also marks the associations as new. However, while in a 1:n or 1:1 association the state of the association changes when the state of one of the ends changes, in many-to-many associations there is a part of the association that is hidden and that will always remain `Added`. (Under the hood a many-to-many association is a `1:n:1` association, the `n` part is not visible in your code).

So this statement...

```
db.DocumentTypes.Add(entity);
```

causes the associations to get the `Added` state, and the subsequent...

```
db.Entry(entity).State = EntityState.Modified;
```

doesn't change this any more.

You have to make sure that for an existing `DocumentType` the state is never changed to `Added`, which you can do by checking its `Id` values, same as you do for `DocumentStatus`.

Also, you have to change the way you set the state of `DocumentStatuses`:

```
foreach (var item in entity.DocumentStatuses)
{
    db.Entry(item).State = item.Id != null
                               ? EntityState.Unchanged
                               : EntityState.Added;
}
```

Comment: that makes sense. BTW, the cast was a copy and paste hang over, I have other objects that use Interfaces, so that is why I had a cast. So the issue is that Frank's change works in that it no longer tries to insert a duplicate 1:n:1 relationship to the table. The issue is that if I add another DocumentStatus to DocumentType.DocumentStatuses, then call this update method, it doesn't create the 1:n:1 record for the newly added DocumentStatus. So we solved one problem, but created a new one.

Comment: I thought the same thing and tried that. But if you look at my Unit Test above, I'm not adding an new Status, but adding a new 1:n:1 relationship with an existing Status. So the EntityState status for item would have an Id so it will always be EntityState.Unchanged, which makes sense because it already exists.

Comment: I can't see what exactly happens in there, but at least this is the direction to go. It works in a simple many-to-many I'm testing out right now.

Comment: If you remove an item from the list and Save, we have the same type of problem, it basically doesn't remove the 1:n:1 relationship.

Comment: You must remove an item after the `DocumentType` and its statusses are attached to the context, otherwise the change tracker will never be aware of the fact that there ever was an item to be removed.

Comment: So removing after context does issue the correct delete statement -- removing the 1:n:1 relationship. It still doesn't add the new relationship. Is there anyway to control, without resorting to creating an inline SQL statement to create the record?

Comment: I starting to think that maybe the best approach is to make this a ReadOnly Collection, and creating a different way to add/remove these 1:n:1 relationships.

Comment: I'm afraid we're getting beyond what we can do through StackOverflow. The only thing I can say is that in a simple many-to-many associations project I can add/remove new and existing associations in the same way as I showed above. Removing must be done after the loop through `DocumentStatuses`, otherwise the `Deleted` state is undone.

Comment: Thanks for trying. I'll convert the list into a ReadOnlyCollection and manage these associations through a separate/dedicated set of methods.